# Can i use predefined variables by concatenating the variable name?

Tags: python, variables

I have variable pairs like this

```
KEY_PasswordExpiryFeature = "PasswordExpiryFeature"
KEY_PasswordExpiryFeature_DEFAULT = "FALSE"
```

i have methods that i call where i have to specify both of those variables.
However, to save me from some brainless typing, i want to only specify the first variable

```
KEY_PasswordExpiryFeature = "PasswordExpiryFeature"
```

and in the receiving method do this

```
def evaluate(et, key):
    print("Evaluating key: %s -> Passed: %s" % (getKeyAttribute(et, key), getValueAttribute(et, key).lower() != VALUEOFVARIABLE("KEY_" + key + "_DEFAULT")))
```

instead of this

```
def evaluate(et, key, default_value):
    print("Evaluating key: %s -> Passed: %s" % (getKeyAttribute(et, key), getValueAttribute(et, key).lower() != default_value))
```

Comment: It's not totally clear what `evaluate` is supposed to be doing.  What kind of thing is `et`?  Is `key` supposed to be something like `KEY_PasswordExpiryFeature`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing around raw variables.  You probably want to encapsulate your variable pairs into some other object.  Two common options would be dictionaries or named tuples.  For example:

```
KEY_PasswordExpiry = {
    "feature": "PasswordExpiryFeature",
    "default": False
}
```

or

```
from collections import namedtuple

Key = namedtuple("Key", ["feature", "default"])

PasswordExpiry = Key(feature="PasswordExpiryFeature", default=False)
```

In the `namedtuple` case, you can then access the `feature` and `default` values of the `PasswordExpiry` key with dot notation.

```
>>> PasswordExpiry.feature
'PasswordExpiryFeature'
>>> PasswordExpiry.default
False
```